# setup.py: renaming src package to project name

Tags: python, python-2.7, distutils

Let's say you have a project called `proj` and in this project you have the following structure:

```
proj/
  dists/
  doc/
  src/
    __init__.py
    xyz.py
    abc.py
  test/
  setup.py
```

As you can see all the content of your project is in the `src` subfolder. How to go about making a distutils distribution package out of the `src` folder?

My naive idea, following [the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html), would've been to write the `setup.py` like this:

```
#omitting basics
setup(
   name='proj',
   packages=['src'],
   package_dir={'proj':'src'}
)
```

But after installing the resulting package to my system, I still have to import `src.xyz` and not `proj.xyz`, which would've been the goal and the expected result.

Answer (score 25):

You could fix it by putting Python package files into `proj/` directory:

```
proj/
  src/
    proj/
      __init__.py
      xyz.py
      abc.py
  setup.py
```

And changing `setup.py` to:

```
# ...
setup(
   name='proj',
   packages=['proj'],
   package_dir={'':'src'}
)
```

It is not required by distutils but other tools might expect the parent directory name of `__init__.py` file to be the same as Python package name i.e., `proj` in this case.

Comment: I did that and it works. Not sure if I understand your last comment, though. You mean there are tools that expect me to have a folder structure like `proj/src/proj` to work as expected? Seems so inefficient. Or am I doing something inefficient here?

Comment: I meant that the directory name: `<name>/__init__.py` should be the same as Python package name i.e., if I see `__init__.py` then just by looking at its parent directory name I know what Python package it is.

Answer (score 23):

This is due to a bug in setuptools reported here: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/250

Basically, it does work but not in dev mode. Now on you have 3 solutions:

- symlink the `src` package as `proj` (and ignore it when comitting), it will works out of the box but is dirty
- change from `src` to `proj`
- create a subdirectory `proj` in `src` and use the following options:

```
packages=['proj'],
package_dir={'proj': 'src/proj'},
```

Comment: Link to setuptools issue: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/250

Comment: Issue's now closed for 3.5+

Answer (score 11):

the correct settings is:

```
#omitting basics
setup(
   name='proj',
   packages=['proj'],
   package_dir={'proj':'src'}
)
```

the src folder should contains `__init__.py` (if file is empty, everthing is exported by default)

in another project:
requirements.txt:

`../relativePathToProject` or name of `package:version`

Comment: *edit: well maybe it does actually work... I might have judged too quickly. I need to check it first.

Comment: For me, with python 3.8 and setuptools 58.0.4, this still installs the package as `src` rather than `proj`.

Comment: The example was tested with python 3.7. I used venv: pip install -r requirements.txt with the relative path to the dependency project

Comment: The solution works also if `src` contains subpackages, but in my case it just cloned the `src` folder.

Comment: I am running Python 3.10 with setuptools 67.8.0 but am running into the same issues as @rudolfbyker when installing in editable mode (`pip install -e .`). Any recommendations on how to navigate that?

Comment: this doesn't seem to work in python3.10, the pip package is called `proj` but in python I still need to do `import src`

Answer (score 4):

You can first use `find_packages` to find all the package names in `src`, then rename them manually to the desired name. Finally, use the `package_dir` option to specify the package convention.

```
import re

from setuptools import find_packages, setup

PACKAGE_NAME = 'proj'
SOURCE_DIRECTORY = 'src'
SOURCE_PACKAGE_REGEX = re.compile(rf'^{SOURCE_DIRECTORY}')

source_packages = find_packages(include=[SOURCE_DIRECTORY, f'{SOURCE_DIRECTORY}.*'])
proj_packages = [SOURCE_PACKAGE_REGEX.sub(PACKAGE_NAME, name) for name in source_packages]

setup(
    name=PACKAGE_NAME,
    packages=proj_packages,
    package_dir={PACKAGE_NAME: SOURCE_DIRECTORY},
    ...
)
```

Comment: I still need to `import src` with this method in python3.10

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Jfs' Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14421176/4028718), if like me you had a directory structure already established that you didn't want to/couldn't change for other reasons, one solution is to temporary copy all of the code to be packaged and then build that.

Here's a makefile with targets which copies all the files across in src to a temp location, and then calls setup.py to build the package, before finally cleaning up after itself.

```
SRC_DIR='src'
TEMP_PACKAGE_DIR='your_shiny_package'

package: prepare_package_dir build_package deploy_package remove_package_dir

# I'm using gemfury, your deployment will probably look different
deploy_package:
    twine upload --repository fury dist/* --verbose

clean_package:
    rm -r dist || echo 'dist removed'
    rm -r ${TEMP_PACKAGE_DIR}.egg-info || echo 'egg-info removed'

build_package: clean_package
    python setup.py sdist

prepare_package_dir:
    mkdir ${TEMP_PACKAGE_DIR}
    cp -R ${SRC_DIR}/* ${TEMP_PACKAGE_DIR}/
    mv ${TEMP_PACKAGE_DIR} ${SRC_DIR}/${TEMP_PACKAGE_DIR}

remove_package_dir:
    rm -rf ${SRC_DIR}/${TEMP_PACKAGE_DIR}
```

and then a setup.py which looks a bit like this:

```py
setup(
    name='your_shiny_package',
    version=version,
    description='some great package...',
    long_description=readme,
    url='https://whereever',
    author='you',
    packages=['src/your_shiny_package'],
    install_requires=parse_all_requirements(),
    zip_safe=False,
    include_package_data=True)
```

Might not be the most efficient, but saves you having to restructure your whole repo permanently.

Usage: just call `make package` either as part of your build pipeline or manually.

Answer (score 0):

The `src` dir is commonly used to keep all the py files in your project. Based on this some developers prefer to rename `src` to the repository name. That is:

```
proj/
  dists/
  doc/
  proj/
    __init__.py
    xyz.py
    abc.py
  test/
  setup.py
```

It means that when you import any module or subpackage, you can always import from `proj` as `from proj import ...`.

If the repository name is not that good to be a package name, e.g. `neetcode-challenges-level-hard`, you can just use another name to call your `src` folder to make it seem to be part of the job:

```
neetcode-challenges-level-hard/
  dists/
  doc/

  neetcode/
    __init__.py
    optimization.py
    tree.py

  test/
  setup.py
```

To import any module you'd use `from neetcode import ...`.

Comment: Please note that "scripts" and ".py files in a module" are not the same thing at all in Python. The confusion between these two makes this answer less valuable. It needs some clarification.

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: It's complicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3

Answer (score -6):

You can try adding the `src` folder to the `PYTHONPATH` before you call the `setup` function:

```
import sys, os
src_path = os.path.join(os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'src')
sys.path.append(src_path)
```

And also, just to be on the safe side, you then change the working directory:

```
os.chdir(src_path)
```

After that, it should all be OK.

<strike>Some other tools for packaging your app support that from within. I thought it was setuptools, turns out it's PyInstaller. But basically, that's what should be done, just enough for your packages to be imported directly.</strike>

Turns out distutils has the `package_dir` directive. That is what you should use, but it *might* work by only adding your package to the `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: I'm not sure you got the problem yet. I'm trying to write a python package that other people can install by themself easily. It's not just about importing stuff you wrote in another folder.

Comment: Yes I understand, but the `setup.py` has to import stuff in another folder in order to work. Once these packages are in your PYTHONPATH, it doesn't matter where they are. If it did not work for you, you'll have to see another way, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not the problem.