# Relative imports in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I want to import a function from another file in the same directory.

Usually, one of the following works:

```
from .mymodule import myfunction
```

```
from mymodule import myfunction
```

...but the other one gives me one of these errors:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mymodule'
```

```
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

Why is this?

Comment: See also: [beyond top level package error in relative import](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30669474/4561887)

Comment: and [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/4561887)

Answer (score 1306, accepted):

> unfortunately, this module needs to be inside the package, and it also
> needs to be runnable as a script, sometimes. Any idea how I could
> achieve that?

It's quite common to have a layout like this...

```
main.py
mypackage/
    __init__.py
    mymodule.py
    myothermodule.py
```

...with a `mymodule.py` like this...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Exported function
def as_int(a):
    return int(a)

# Test function for module  
def _test():
    assert as_int('1') == 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _test()
```

...a `myothermodule.py` like this...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from .mymodule import as_int

# Exported function
def add(a, b):
    return as_int(a) + as_int(b)

# Test function for module  
def _test():
    assert add('1', '1') == 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _test()
```

...and a `main.py` like this...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from mypackage.myothermodule import add

def main():
    print(add('1', '1'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

...which works fine when you run `main.py` or `mypackage/mymodule.py`, but fails with `mypackage/myothermodule.py`, due to the relative import...

```
from .mymodule import as_int
```

The way you're supposed to run it is by using the -m option and giving the path in the Python module system (rather than in the filesystem)...

```
python3 -m mypackage.myothermodule
```

...but it's somewhat verbose, and doesn't mix well with a shebang line like `#!/usr/bin/env python3`.

An alternative is to avoid using relative imports, and just use...

```
from mypackage.mymodule import as_int
```

Either way, you'll need to run from the parent of `mypackage`, or add that directory to `PYTHONPATH` (either one will ensure that `mypackage` is in the sys.path [module search path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys_path_init.html)). Or, if you want it to work "out of the box", you can frob the `PYTHONPATH` in code first with this...

```
import sys
import os

SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(SCRIPT_DIR))

from mypackage.mymodule import as_int
```

It's kind of a pain, but there's a clue as to why in [an email](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-April/006793.html) written by a certain Guido van Rossum...

> I'm -1 on this and on any other proposed twiddlings of the `__main__`
> machinery. The only use case seems to be running scripts that happen
> to be living inside a module's directory, which I've always seen as an
> antipattern. To make me change my mind you'd have to convince me that
> it isn't.

Whether running scripts inside a package is an antipattern or not is subjective, but personally I find it really useful in a package I have which contains some custom wxPython widgets, so I can run the script for any of the source files to display a `wx.Frame` containing only that widget for testing purposes.

Comment: A better way to get SCRIPTDIR is given in [a comment of Import a module from a relative path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path?lq=1#comment15918105_6098238) as `os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))` if your confident that your module has always a proper `file` you could also use `os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))`.

Comment: @marcz: Please use `os.path.abspath()` instead of `os.path.realpath()`. There rarely is a need to resolve all symlinks along the path, and doing so can actually break advanced symlink use to collect the right packages in a single 'virtual' directory.

Comment: One useful use case of such _antipattern_ would be having your tests inside some sub directories of your project which should test other components of your software?!

Comment: @Student that is the exact use case I am attempting to solve and how I ended up here

Comment: For help understanding the `sys.path.append()` usage at the bottom of this answer, see [my comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath/3402176#comment134432508_3402176) and the official documentation links in that comment. The [`PYTHONPATH` system variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) is being changed whenever you append to the [`sys.path` list of strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) in your Python program. It's now starting to make sense what is going on there in this answer.

Comment: Worked for me (am using gdb python api) although I had to use `sys.path.append(SCRIPT_DIR)` because two `os.path.dirname` takes you to the parent dir?

Comment: @Student that is the exact use case I am attempting to solve and how I ended up here - me too :(

Comment: I'm using python to do scientific data analysis and generate some paper plot. so, not like apps there is only one entrance. there will be many folders in my project, and I need to execute every script separately. However, these scripts are not independent, they may share some tool or method functions. In this case, python's confusing relative import make modularization complex.

Comment: Dear god! Is there no end to the Python madness?

Answer (score 657):

## Explanation

From [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)

> Relative imports use a module's __name__ attribute to determine that
>   module's position in the package hierarchy. If the module's name does
>   not contain any package information (e.g. it is set to '__main__')
>   **then relative imports are resolved as if the module were a top level
>   module**, regardless of where the module is actually located on the file
>   system.

At some point [PEP 338](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/) conflicted with [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/):

> ... relative imports rely on *__name__* to determine the current
>   module's position in the package hierarchy. In a main module, the
>   value of *__name__* is always *'__main__'*, so explicit relative imports
>   will always fail (as they only work for a module inside a package)

and to address the issue, [PEP 366](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) introduced the top level variable [`__package__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__package__):

> By adding a new module level attribute, this PEP allows relative
>   imports to work automatically if the module is executed using the *-m*
>   switch. A small amount of boilerplate in the module itself will allow
>   the relative imports to work when the file is executed by name. [...] When it [the attribute] is present, relative imports will be based on this attribute
>   rather than the module *__name__* attribute. [...] When the main module is specified by its filename, then the *__package__* attribute will be set to *None*. [...] **When the import system encounters an explicit relative import in a
>   module without __package__ set (or with it set to None), it will
>   calculate and store the correct value** (**__name__.rpartition('.')[0]
>   for normal modules** and *__name__* for package initialisation modules)

(emphasis mine)

If the `__name__` is `'__main__'`, `__name__.rpartition('.')[0]` returns empty string. This is why there's empty string literal in the error description:

```
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

The relevant part of the CPython's [`PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject` function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/9d65a195246b/Python/import.c#l1494):

```c
if (PyDict_GetItem(interp->modules, package) == NULL) {
    PyErr_Format(PyExc_SystemError,
            "Parent module %R not loaded, cannot perform relative "
            "import", package);
    goto error;
}
```

CPython raises this exception if it was unable to find `package` (the name of the package) in `interp->modules` (accessible as [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules)). Since `sys.modules` is *"a dictionary that maps module names to modules which have already been loaded"*, it's now clear that **the parent module must be explicitly absolute-imported before performing relative import**.

***Note:***  The patch from the [issue 18018](http://bugs.python.org/issue18018) has added [another `if` block](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c4e4886c6052/Python/import.c#l1494), which will be executed **before** the code above:

```c
if (PyUnicode_CompareWithASCIIString(package, "") == 0) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ImportError,
            "attempted relative import with no known parent package");
    goto error;
} /* else if (PyDict_GetItem(interp->modules, package) == NULL) {
    ...
*/
```

If `package` (same as above) is empty string, the error message will be

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

However, you will only see this in Python 3.6 or newer.

## Solution #1: Run your script using -m

Consider a directory (which is a Python [package](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-package)):

```
.
├── package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── module.py
│   └── standalone.py
```

All of the files in *package* begin with the same 2 lines of code:

```
from pathlib import Path
print('Running' if __name__ == '__main__' else 'Importing', Path(__file__).resolve())
```

I'm including these two lines *only* to make the order of operations obvious. We can ignore them completely, since they don't affect the execution.

*__init__.py* and *module.py* contain only those two lines (i.e., they are effectively empty).

*standalone.py* additionally attempts to import *module.py* via relative import:

```
from . import module  # explicit relative import
```

We're well aware that `/path/to/python/interpreter package/standalone.py` will fail. However, we can run the module with the [`-m` command line option](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=#cmdoption-m) that will *"search [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) for the named module and execute its contents as the `__main__` module"*:

```bash
vaultah@base:~$ python3 -i -m package.standalone
Importing /home/vaultah/package/__init__.py
Running /home/vaultah/package/standalone.py
Importing /home/vaultah/package/module.py
>>> __file__
'/home/vaultah/package/standalone.py'
>>> __package__
'package'
>>> # The __package__ has been correctly set and module.py has been imported.
... # What's inside sys.modules?
... import sys
>>> sys.modules['__main__']
<module 'package.standalone' from '/home/vaultah/package/standalone.py'>
>>> sys.modules['package.module']
<module 'package.module' from '/home/vaultah/package/module.py'>
>>> sys.modules['package']
<module 'package' from '/home/vaultah/package/__init__.py'>
```

`-m` does all the importing stuff for you and automatically sets `__package__`, but you can do that yourself in the

## Solution #2: Set __package__ manually

***Please treat it as a proof of concept rather than an actual solution. It isn't well-suited for use in real-world code.***

[PEP 366](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) has a workaround to this problem, however, it's incomplete, because setting `__package__` alone is not enough. You're going to need to import at least *N* preceding packages in the module hierarchy, where *N* is the number of parent directories (relative to the directory of the script) that will be searched for the module being imported.

Thus,

1. Add the parent directory of the *Nth* predecessor of the current module to `sys.path`
2. Remove the current file's directory from `sys.path`
3. Import the parent module of the current module using its fully-qualified name
4. Set `__package__` to the fully-qualified name from *2*
5. Perform the relative import

I'll borrow files from the *Solution #1* and add some more subpackages:

```
package
├── __init__.py
├── module.py
└── subpackage
    ├── __init__.py
    └── subsubpackage
        ├── __init__.py
        └── standalone.py
```

This time *standalone.py* will import *module.py* from the *package* package using the following relative import

```
from ... import module  # N = 3
```

We'll need to precede that line with the boilerplate code, to make it work.

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path

if __name__ == '__main__' and __package__ is None:
    file = Path(__file__).resolve()
    parent, top = file.parent, file.parents[3]

    sys.path.append(str(top))
    try:
        sys.path.remove(str(parent))
    except ValueError: # Already removed
        pass

    import package.subpackage.subsubpackage
    __package__ = 'package.subpackage.subsubpackage'

from ... import module # N = 3
```

It allows us to execute *standalone.py* by filename:

```bash
vaultah@base:~$ python3 package/subpackage/subsubpackage/standalone.py
Running /home/vaultah/package/subpackage/subsubpackage/standalone.py
Importing /home/vaultah/package/__init__.py
Importing /home/vaultah/package/subpackage/__init__.py
Importing /home/vaultah/package/subpackage/subsubpackage/__init__.py
Importing /home/vaultah/package/module.py
```

A more general solution wrapped in a function can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/vaultah/d63cb4c86be2774377aa674b009f759a). Example usage:

```
if __name__ == '__main__' and __package__ is None:
    import_parents(level=3) # N = 3

from ... import module
from ...module.submodule import thing
```

## Solution #3: Use absolute imports and [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

The steps are -

1. Replace explicit relative imports with equivalent absolute imports
2. Install `package` to make it importable

For instance, the directory structure may be as follows

```
.
├── project
│   ├── package
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── module.py
│   │   └── standalone.py
│   └── setup.py
```

where *setup.py* is

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name = 'your_package_name',
    packages = find_packages(),
)
```

The rest of the files were borrowed from the *Solution #1*.

Installation will allow you to import the package regardless of your working directory (assuming there'll be no naming issues).

We can modify *standalone.py* to use this advantage (step 1):

```
from package import module  # absolute import
```

Change your working directory to `project` and run `/path/to/python/interpreter setup.py install --user` (`--user` installs the package in [your site-packages directory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#site.USER_SITE)) (step 2):

```bash
vaultah@base:~$ cd project
vaultah@base:~/project$ python3 setup.py install --user
```

Let's verify that it's now possible to run *standalone.py* as a script:

```bash
vaultah@base:~/project$ python3 -i package/standalone.py
Running /home/vaultah/project/package/standalone.py
Importing /home/vaultah/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/your_package_name-0.0.0-py3.6.egg/package/__init__.py
Importing /home/vaultah/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/your_package_name-0.0.0-py3.6.egg/package/module.py
>>> module
<module 'package.module' from '/home/vaultah/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/your_package_name-0.0.0-py3.6.egg/package/module.py'>
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules['package']
<module 'package' from '/home/vaultah/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/your_package_name-0.0.0-py3.6.egg/package/__init__.py'>
>>> sys.modules['package.module']
<module 'package.module' from '/home/vaultah/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/your_package_name-0.0.0-py3.6.egg/package/module.py'>
```

***Note***: If you decide to go down this route, you'd be better off using [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) to install packages in isolation.

## Solution #4: Use absolute imports and some boilerplate code

Frankly, the installation is not necessary - you could add some boilerplate code to your script to make absolute imports work.

I'm going to borrow files from *Solution #1* and change *standalone.py*:

1. Add the parent directory of *package* to `sys.path` *before* attempting to import anything from *package* using absolute imports:

   ```
   import sys
   from pathlib import Path # if you haven't already done so
   file = Path(__file__).resolve()
   parent, root = file.parent, file.parents[1]
   sys.path.append(str(root))

   # Additionally remove the current file's directory from sys.path
   try:
       sys.path.remove(str(parent))
   except ValueError: # Already removed
       pass
   ```
2. Replace the relative import by the absolute import:

   ```
   from package import module  # absolute import
   ```

*standalone.py* runs without problems:

```bash
vaultah@base:~$ python3 -i package/standalone.py
Running /home/vaultah/package/standalone.py
Importing /home/vaultah/package/__init__.py
Importing /home/vaultah/package/module.py
>>> module
<module 'package.module' from '/home/vaultah/package/module.py'>
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules['package']
<module 'package' from '/home/vaultah/package/__init__.py'>
>>> sys.modules['package.module']
<module 'package.module' from '/home/vaultah/package/module.py'>
```

I feel that I should warn you: try not to do this, *especially* if your project has a complex structure.

---

As a side note, [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) recommends the use of absolute imports, but states that in some scenarios explicit relative imports are acceptable:

> Absolute imports are recommended, as they are usually more readable
>   and tend to be better behaved (or at least give better error
>   messages). [...] However, explicit relative imports are an acceptable
>   alternative to absolute imports, especially when dealing with complex
>   package layouts where using absolute imports would be unnecessarily
>   verbose.

Comment: Is it possible to set `__package__` manually if name is `__main__` in order to solve the problem?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I'm using nltk package, I'm getting an error: ` File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 115, in <module>
    from nltk.decorators import decorator, memoize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/nltk/decorators.py", line 23, in <module>
    sys.path = [p for p in sys.path if "nltk" not in p]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/nltk/decorators.py", line 23, in <listcomp>
    sys.path = [p for p in sys.path if "nltk" not in p]
TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable
`

Comment: One minor gotcha with solution 2, is that this will fail if the file you're trying to run as a script from the command line has the same name as the value of `__package__`, as the file you're trying to run will then take precedence and be imported instead of the package.

Comment: You can also import a file by file path (relative too): https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly

Comment: `python -m` worked for me

Comment: This is an infuriating amount of complexity to add to accomplish something done *so trivially* in a language like Node.js. The import system in Python is done terribly, objectively speaking. I read the [PEP document on this](https://peps.python.org/pep-0328/), they basically said "Users suggested a better solution, but it would be too much of a change", essentially admitting they designed the import feature badly and it's too late to *really* fix it. The fact that we even need an `__init__.py` in every directory is so silly, it's hard to believe it's real when you first learn of it.

Comment: Some years later (today) please have a look at the `--editable` option of `pip` to "install" a package in _Development Mode_.

Comment: I cam here for quick and simple solution but now looking at the length of answer makes me delirious about how confusing this import-problem is.

Comment: @SyedShaharyaarHussain  It amazed me that this question has been around for 9 years, and still popular today with new comments and new ansawers.

Comment: Is this different between different Python 3 versions? Like 3.8 vs 3.10?

Comment: 2023 and this problem still exists

Comment: adding this worked for me import sys ;sys.path.append(".")

Comment: That's nice and easy then.

Answer (score 297):

**Put this inside your package's __init__.py file**:

```
# For relative imports to work in Python 3.6
import os, sys; sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

Assuming your package is like this:

```
├── project
│   ├── package
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── module1.py
│   │   └── module2.py
│   └── setup.py
```

Now use regular imports in you package, like:

```
# in module2.py
from module1 import class1
```

This works in both python 2 and 3.

Comment: I also think this deserves more votes. Putting this in every `__init__.py` will basically solve all the relative import errors.

Comment: I can't speak for others, but I tend to avoid modifying `sys.path` because I'm concerned it might affect other code. (Partially this is because I don't know the intricacies of how it works.)

Comment: @pianoJames I know what you mean, this (seemingly, after a lot of screwing around) magic fix does seem a little too easy. But it works. Would be interested not know from those-that-know if this is has negative side effects.

Comment: Wiat if you have two modules with the same name in two different packages - won't it cause a collision?

Comment: Re: "This works in both python 2 and 3."
That said if you have no installation scripts to run then the use of \_\_init\_\_.py has not been needed since python 3.3+

Comment: In my case, `module1` does not contain a Class, only functions. Then I get `No module named 'module1'`

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi I confirm a drawback is if you have two files from different modules with same name. 

When running python -m pytest, I have this conflict issue. Would be great if the author could provide a solution for it.

Comment: Where is the executable script here? If I try to run some script that imports from `package` I get an error still

Comment: This is not a relative import. It's a global import that happens to resolve to the relative file.

Answer (score 72):

I ran into this issue.  A hack workaround is importing via an if/else block like follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#myothermodule

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from mymodule import as_int
else:
    from .mymodule import as_int


# Exported function
def add(a, b):
    return as_int(a) + as_int(b)

# Test function for module  
def _test():
    assert add('1', '1') == 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _test()
```

Comment: It is `SystemError` here. (Py 3.4)

Comment: @Perkins Well... in most cases it _wouldn't_. I think relative imports may be the exception though.

Comment: Worked for me with python 3.8.  I tried many other solutions and this is the first one that lets me do development in Emacs on the files within the folders as I am building the package.  Other advice to make the package work was useless to me, I need to develop the package itself.

Comment: @pauljohn32 If you're developing a package you should be testing it by installing it with an editable pip install (`pip install -e .` from the package root where `setup.py` is) and importing it as a package in your test files, not meddling around with conditional imports like this.

Comment: Simplest solution for me (Python 3.9) w/out messing with `sys.path`. Wish it was prettier (and unnecessary), but c'est la vie. +1

Comment: Not working with `-m`: `python3 -m  packageDir.subDir.myothermodule`. But yes `python3   packageDir/subDir/myothermodule.py` or as a package `python3 -c "import packageDir.subDir.myothermodule as my; my.test()"`. A `try-except` (instead of  `if-else`) would make it work in all these 3 cases as @darvin-rio [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3/68312469#68312469)

Answer (score 51):

> SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

This means you are running a module inside the package as a script. Mixing scripts inside packages is *tricky* and should be avoided if at all possible. Use a wrapper script that imports the package and runs your `scripty` function instead.

If your top-level directory is called `foo`, which is on your `PYTHONPATH` module search path, and you have a package `bar` there (it is a directory you'd expect an `__init__.py` file in), scripts should *not be placed inside `bar`*, but should live on in `foo` *at best*.

Note that *scripts* differ from *modules* here in that they are used as a filename argument to the `python` command, either by using `python <filename>` or via a `#!` (shebang) line. It is loaded *directly* as the [`__main__` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#module-__main__) (this is why `if __name__ == "__main__":` works in scripts), and there is no package context to build on for relative imports.

### Your options

- If you can, package your project with `setuptools` (or `poetry` or `flit`, which can help simplify packaging), and create [console script entrypoints](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html#console-scripts); installing your project with `pip` then creates scripts that know how to import your package properly. You can install your package locally with `pip install -e .`, so it can still be edited in-place.
- Otherwise, never, ever, use `python path/to/packagename/file.py`, always use `python path/to/script.py` and `script.py` can use `from packagename import ...`.
- As a fallback, you could use the [`-m` command-line switch](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) to tell Python to import a module and use that as the `__main__` file instead. This does not work with a shebang line, as there is no script file any more, however.

  If you use `python -m foo.bar` and `foo/bar.py` is found in a `sys.path` directory, that is then imported and executed as `__main__` with the right package context. If `bar` is also a package, inside `foo/`, it must have a `__main__.py` file (so `foo/bar/__main__.py` as the path from the `sys.path` directory).
- In extreme circumstances, add the metadata Python uses to resolve relative imports by setting `__package__` directly; the file `foo/bar/spam.py`, importable as `foo.bar.spam`, is given the global `__package__ = "foo.bar"`. It is just another global, like `__file__` and `__name__`, set by Python when imported.

### On `sys.path`

The above all requires that your package can be imported, which means it needs to be found in one of the directories (or zipfiles) listed in [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path). There are several options here too:

- The directory where `path/to/script.py` was found (so `path/to`) is automatically added to `sys.path`. Executing `python path/to/foo.py` adds `path/to` to `sys.path`.
- If you packaged your project (with `setuptools`, `poetry`, `flit` or another Python packaging tool), and installed it, the package has been added to the right place already.
- As a last resort, add the right directory to `sys.path` yourself. If the package can be located relatively to the script file, use the `__file__` variable in the script global namespace (e.g. using the [`pathlib.Path` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path), `HERE = Path(__file__).resolve().parent` is a reference to the directory the file lives in, as absolute path).

Comment: I moved my file, indeed, a script, to the top-level directory (`src`) and changed the relative import to a regular (absolute?) import. Now it works. I'm not happy that I had to move my file, but I'm glad it now runs.

Answer (score 29):

**TL;DR**

You can only relatively import modules **inside another module in the same package.**

**Concept Clarify**

We see a lot of example code in books/docs/articles, they show us how to relatively import a module, but when we do so, it fails.

The reason is, put it in a simple sentence, we did not run the code as the python module mechanism expects, even though the code is written totally right. It's like some kind of runtime thing.

**Module loading is depended on how you run the code.** That is the source of confusion.

**What is a module?**

A module is a python file when and only when it is being imported by another file. Given a file `mod.py`, is it a module? Yes and No, if you run `python mod.py`, it is not a module, because it is not imported.

**What is a package?**

A package is a folder that includes Python module(s).

BTW, `__init__.py` is not necessary from python 3.3, if you don't need any package initialization or auto-load submodules. You don't need to place a blank `__init__.py` in a directory.

That proves a package is just a folder as long as there are files being imported.

---

**Real Answer**

Now, this description becomes clearer.

> You can only relatively import modules **inside another module in the same package.**

Given a directory:

```
. CWD
|-- happy_maker.py # content: print('Sends Happy')
`-- me.py # content: from . import happy_maker
```

Run `python me.py`, we got `attempted relative import with no known parent package`

`me.py` is run directly, it is not a module, and we can't use relative import in it.

**Solution 1**

Use `import happy_maker` instead of `from . import happy_maker`

**Solution 2**

Switch our working directory to the parent folder.

```
. CWD
|-- happy
|   |-- happy_maker.py
    `-- me.py
```

Run `python -m happy.me`.

When we are in the directory that includes `happy`, `happy` is a package, `me.py, happy_maker.py` are modules, we can use relative import now, and we still want to run `me.py`, so we use `-m` which means run the module as a script.

---

**Python Idiom**

```
. CWD
|-- happy
|   |-- happy_maker.py # content: print('Sends Happy')
|   `-- me.py # content: from . import happy_maker
`-- main.py # content: import happy.me
```

This structure is the python idiom. `main` is our script, best practice in Python. Finally, we got there.

---

**Siblings or Grandparents**

Another common need:

```
.
|-- happy
|   |-- happy_maker.py
|   `-- me.py
`-- sad
    `-- sad_maker.py
```

We want to import `sad_maker` in `me.py`, How to do that?

First, we need to make `happy` and `sad` in the same package, so we have to go up a directory level.  And then `from ..sad import sad_maker` in the `me.py`.

That is all.

Comment: `from . import happy_maker` in `me.py` (the *Python Idiom*) can be shortened to just `from happy_maker`, right? What if you have `tests` subdir under `happy` with a script `test_happy.py` which need relative imports from `happy_maker.py`? Will `from .. import happy_maker` (with two dots) work there?

Comment: most clear solution!

Answer (score 22):

For PyCharm users:

I also was getting `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` because I was adding the `.` notation to silence a PyCharm parsing error. PyCharm innaccurately reports not being able to find:

`lib.thing import function`

If you change it to:

`.lib.thing import function`

it silences the error but then you get the aforementioned `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`. Just ignore PyCharm's parser. It's wrong and the code runs fine despite what it says.

Comment: usually the parser in the IDE is wrong because its path has not been set. You should find the option which specifies the CWD (current workind directory) and set it to the same thing you use on the command line

Comment: After far too much futzing around with Python and Pycharm, I'm going to:
`try:
    from .mname import symbol
except:
    from mname import symbol`

Comment: @gerardw PyCharm looks at symbols based on the base folder of the project directory. If it's flopping on you that *typically* means there is something wonky about the location from which you're opening the project. You might try opening it in a different root directory. This is what Ciprian was talking about. Might help you - but maybe not 

Answer (score 15):

To obviate this problem, I devised a solution with the [repackage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/repackage/0.5) package, which has worked for me for some time. It adds the upper directory to the lib path:

```
import repackage
repackage.up()
from mypackage.mymodule import myfunction
```

Repackage can make relative imports that work in a wide range of cases, using an intelligent strategy (inspecting the call stack).

Comment: I tried it. Still failed: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: @pauljohn32 How did you do your import? Also, `up()` goes only one level in the directory hierarchy. You would need to check what you actually find there.

Comment: @fraulau. Thanks. I've been testing.  I was trying to leave relative import after up().  That's wrong, I see from your example.  If I rewrite as absolute, then up() seems have same effect as `sys.path.append` to add the "containing folder" in the search path.  Then the absolute paths work.

Answer (score 15):

#### TL;DR: to @Aya's answer, updated with `pathlib` library, and working for Jupyter notebooks where `__file__` is not defined:

You want to import `my_function` defined under `../my_Folder_where_the_package_lives/my_package.py`
respect to where you are writing the code.

Then do:

```
import os
import sys
import pathlib

PACKAGE_PARENT = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent
#PACKAGE_PARENT = pathlib.Path.cwd().parent # if on jupyter notebook
SCRIPT_DIR = PACKAGE_PARENT / "my_Folder_where_the_package_lives"
sys.path.append(str(SCRIPT_DIR))

from my_package import my_function
```

Comment: I think you meant `pathlib.Path.cwd().parent` instead of `Path.cwd().parent`?

Comment: My god, I've searched EVERYWHERE. How is this that difficult?

Comment: @PabloCánovas The difference between showing and explaining, I guess.

Comment: @SeF Your main answer was clearer than this comment lol. Thanks a lot btw!!

Answer (score 13):

Hopefully, this will be of value to someone out there - I went through half a dozen stackoverflow posts trying to figure out relative imports similar to whats posted above here. I set up everything as suggested but I was still hitting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_module_name'`

Since I was just developing locally and playing around, I hadn't created/run a `setup.py` file. I also hadn't apparently set my `PYTHONPATH`.

I realized that when I ran my code as I had been when the tests were in the same directory as the module, I couldn't find my module:

```
$ python3 test/my_module/module_test.py                                                                                                               2.4.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/my_module/module_test.py", line 6, in <module>
    from my_module.module import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_module'
```

However, when I explicitly specified the path things started to work:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=. python3 test/my_module/module_test.py                                                                                                  2.4.0
...........
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 11 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

So, in the event that anyone has tried a few suggestions, believes their code is structured correctly and still finds themselves in a similar situation as myself try either of the following if you don't export the current directory to your PYTHONPATH:

1. Run your code and explicitly include the path like so:
   `$ PYTHONPATH=. python3 test/my_module/module_test.py`
2. To avoid calling `PYTHONPATH=.`, create a `setup.py` file with contents like the following and run `python setup.py development` to add packages to the path:

> ```
> # setup.py
> from setuptools import setup, find_packages
>
> setup(
>     name='sample',
>     packages=find_packages()
> )
> ```

Comment: Through  setting  Enviroment 【PYTHONPATH=.】 , it works for me in any scene !  Awesome Answer .

Answer (score 11):

My boilerplate to make a `module` with relative imports in a `package` runnable standalone.

`package/module.py`

```py
## Standalone boilerplate before relative imports
if __package__ is None:                  
    DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
    sys.path.insert(0, str(DIR.parent))
    __package__ = DIR.name

from . import variable_in__init__py
from . import other_module_in_package
...
```

Now you can use your module in any fashion:

1. Run module as usual: `python -m package.module`
2. Use it as a module: `python -c 'from package import module'`
3. Run it standalone: `python package/module.py`
4. or with shebang (`#!/bin/env python`) just: `package/module.py`

**NB!** Using `sys.path.append` instead of `sys.path.insert` will give you a hard to trace error if your `module` has the same name as your `package`. E.g. `my_script/my_script.py`

Of course if you have relative imports from higher levels in your package hierarchy, than this is not enough, but for most cases, it's just okay.

Comment: Thanks for this @Andor, it helped me solve my case. For me __package__ was preset to an empty string, so this boilerplate condition worked: ````if not __package__: [set __package__]````

Comment: Worked like a charm. I needed to add one more `.parent` to line 3, but that's specific to my case of nested packages. Anyhow, thanks!

Comment: You need to add "from pathlib import Path", but otherwise works for me.  Thanks!

Comment: This is also what I usually do. I am surprised of not seeing this solution in top rated answers, and why.

Answer (score 9):

I was getting this **ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package**

In my program I was using the file from current path for importing its function.

```
from .filename import function
```

Then I modified the current path *(Dot)* with package name. Which resolved my issue.

```
from package_name.filename import function
```

I hope the above answer helps you.

Comment: What is `package_name` in your scenario?

Comment: @mins that was my custom package.

Answer (score 8):

I needed to run python3 from the main project directory to make it work.

For example, if the project has the following structure:

```
project_demo/
├── main.py
├── some_package/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── project_configs.py
└── test/
    └── test_project_configs.py
```

#### Solution

I would run python3 inside folder *project_demo/* and then perform a

```
from some_package import project_configs
```

Answer (score 8):

### Importing from same directory

Firstly, you can import from the same directory.

Here is the file structure...

```
Folder
 |
 ├─ Scripts
 |   ├─ module123.py
 |
 ├─ main.py
 ├─ script123.py
```

Here is main.py

```py
from . import script123
from Scripts import module123
```

As you can see, importing from `.` imports from current directory.

> Note: if running using anything but IDLE, make sure that your terminal is navigated to the same directory as the `main.py` file before running.

Also, importing from a local folder also works.

### Importing from parent directory

As seen in [my GitHub gist here](https://gist.github.com/Password-Classified/711d3cf01032a589b05a1a239ae2179e),  there is the following method.

Take the following file tree...

```
ParentDirectory
 ├─ Folder
 |   |
 |   ├─ Scripts
 |   |   ├─ module123.py
 |   |
 |   ├─ main.py
 |   ├─ script123.py
 |
 ├─ parentModule.py
```

Then, just add this code to the top of your `main.py` file.

```py
import inspect
import os
import sys

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parent_dir = os.path.dirname(current_dir)
sys.path.insert(0, parent_dir)

from ParentDirectory import Stuff
```

Comment: I see examples like your main.py example constantly, but I'm never able to recreate them. Would you be willing to peek at this repo and tell me what I've done wrong?
https://github.com/Adam-Hoelscher/relative-imports-python3

Comment: Sure! Just doing that now.

Comment: Would you mind raising an issue on your repository, and paste the error callback there? It'd be easier than on  the comments here. I need to see the error.

Comment: If I've understood your ask correctly, then it's done. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks

Comment: @AdamHoelscher an extra note, if you run you script with PowerShell, it will return an error, whereas Command Prompt will not. Which terminal did you use? Could a change in terminal actually be where you solved your problem?

Answer (score 6):

I tried all of the above to no avail, only to realize I mistakenly had a `-` in my package name.

In short, don't have `-` in the directory where `__init__.py` is. I've never felt elated after finding out such inanity.

Comment: This sounds like a bug that should be reported.

Comment: @JohnM. Really, somehow I'm under the impression that ``-`` in package name is illegal, or at least frowned upon

Answer (score 6):

Here is a three-liner for those who disagree with [Guido](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16985066/3512356):

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
sys.path.append(str(Path(sys.argv[0]).absolute().parent.parent))
```

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE:** Discovered that this fails when the executable is called by a relative path. The solution is to use `resolve()` instead of `absolute()`:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
sys.path.append(str(Path(sys.argv[0]).resolve().parent.parent))
```

Answer (score 4):

if both packages are in your import path (sys.path), and the module/class you want is in example/example.py, then to access the class without relative import try:

```
from example.example import fkt
```

Answer (score 4):

If none of the above worked for you, you can specify the module explicitly.

**Directory:**

```
├── Project
│     ├── Dir
│     │    ├── __init__.py
│     │    ├── module.py
│     │    └── standalone.py
```

**Solution:**

```
#in standalone.py
from Project.Dir.module import ...
```

> module - the module to be imported

Answer (score 3):

I think the best solution is to create a package for your module:
[Here](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) is more info on how to do it.

Once you have a package you don't need to worry about relative import, you can just do absolute imports.

Comment: The information's behind the links are today outdated (last update 2016) and wrong (e.g. `tests` folder inside the package folder). Please use [official python docs about packaing](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Will update the link now

Answer (score 2):

I encounter this a lot when I am working with Django, since a lot of functionality is performed from the `manage.py` script but I also want to have some of my modules runnable directly as scripts as well (ideally you would make them `manage.py` directives but we're not there yet).

This is a mock up of what such a project might look like;

```
├── dj_app
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── ops
│   │   ├── bar.py
│   │   └── foo.py
│   ├── script.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── utils.py
│   └── views.py
└── manage.py
```

The important parts here being `manage.py`, `dj_app/script.py`, and `dj_app/tests.py`. We also have submodules `dj_app/ops/bar.py` and `dj_app/ops/foo.py` which contain more items we want to use throughout the project.

The source of the issue commonly comes from wanting your `dj_app/script.py` script methods to have test cases in `dj_app/tests.py` which get invoked when you run `manage.py test`.

This is how I set up the project and its `import`s;

```
# dj_app/ops/foo.py
# Foo operation methods and classes
foo_val = "foo123"
```

.

```
# dj_app/ops/bar.py
# Bar operations methods and classes
bar_val = "bar123"
```

.

```
# dj_app/script.py
# script to run app methods from CLI

# if run directly from command line
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from ops.bar import bar_val
    from ops.foo import foo_val

# otherwise
else:
    from .ops.bar import bar_val
    from .ops.foo import foo_val

def script_method1():
    print("this is script_method1")
    print("bar_val: {}".format(bar_val))
    print("foo_val: {}".format(foo_val))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("running from the script")
    script_method1()
```

.

```
# dj_app/tests.py
# test cases for the app
# do not run this directly from CLI or the imports will break
from .script import script_method1
from .ops.bar import bar_val
from .ops.foo import foo_val 

def main():
    print("Running the test case")
    print("testing script method")
    script_method1()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("running tests from command line")
    main()
```

.

```
# manage.py
# just run the test cases for this example
import dj_app.tests
dj_app.tests.main()
```

.

Running the test cases from `manage.py`;

```
$ python3 manage.py
Running the test case
testing script method
this is script_method1
bar_val: bar123
foo_val: foo123
```

Running the script on its own;

```
$ python3 dj_app/script.py
running from the script
this is script_method1
bar_val: bar123
foo_val: foo123
```

Note that you get an error if you try to run the `test.py` directly however, so don't do that;

```
$ python3 dj_app/tests.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dj_app/tests.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .script import script_method1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.script'; '__main__' is not a package
```

If I run into more complicated situations for imports, I usually end up implementing something like this to hack through it;

```
import os
import sys
THIS_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, THIS_DIR)
from script import script_method1
sys.path.pop(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

This my project structure

```
├── folder
|   | 
│   ├── moduleA.py
|   |   |
|   |   └--function1()
|   |       └~~ uses function2()
|   | 
│   └── moduleB.py
|       | 
|       └--function2()
|   
└── main.py
     └~~ uses function1()
```

Here my `moduleA` imports `moduleB` and `main` imports `moduleA`

I added the snippet below in `moduleA` to import `moduleB`

```
try:
    from .moduleB import function2 
except:
    from moduleB import function2
```

Now I can execute both `main.py` as well as `moduleA.py` individually

Is this a solution ?

Comment: I would use `sys.version_info[0]` to check if you are on python 2 or 3, or I would bind the exception to `ImportError `.
 Though in python 3 the relative path may not be a python package, and so the solution may not work either. It depends on the location of moduleB. (also modules should be in snake case by convention).

Comment: I independently came to this solution as well. I don't like it, but with the import system changing its semantics depending on unknown variables for unknown reasons, I think it's the best we can do.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error and my project structure was like

```
->project
  ->vendors
    ->vendors.py
  ->main.py
```

I was trying to call like this

```
from .vendors.Amazon import Amazom_Purchase
```

Here it was throwing an error so I fixed it simply by removing the first . from the statement

```
from vendors.Amazon import Amazom_Purchase
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wouldn't think `.` causes the error. Worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's good to note that sometimes the cache causes of all it.
I've tried different things after re-arranging classes into new directories, and relative import started to work after I removed the `__pycache__`.

Answer (score 1):

The below solution is tested on **Python3**

```
├── classes
|   |
|   ├──__init__.py
|   | 
│   ├── userclass.py
|   |   |
|   |   └--viewDetails()
|   |       
|   | 
│   └── groupclass.py
|       | 
|       └--viewGroupDetails()
|   
└── start.py
     └~~ uses function1()
```

Now, in order to use viewDetails of userclass or viewGroupDetails of groupclass define that in _ *init* _.py of classess directory first.

Ex: In  _ *init* _.py

```
from .userclasss import viewDetails

from .groupclass import viewGroupDetails
```

Step2: Now, in start.py we can directly import viewDetails

Ex: In start.py

```
from classes import viewDetails
from classes import viewGroupDetails
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem when trying to write a python file that can be loaded either as a module or an executable script.

## Setup

```
/path/to/project/
├── __init__.py
└── main.py
    └── mylib/
        ├── list_util.py
        └── args_util.py
```

with:

**`main.py:`**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import mylib.args_util

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f'{mylib.args_util.parseargs(sys.argv[1:])=}')
```

**`mylib/list_util.py:`**

```
def to_int_list(args):
    return [int(x) for x in args]
```

**`mylib/args_util.py:`**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from . import list_util as lu

def parseargs(args):
    return sum(lu.to_int_list(args))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f'{parseargs(sys.argv[1:])=}')
```

### Output

```
$ ./main.py 1 2 3
mylib.args_util.parseargs(sys.argv[1:])=6

$ mylib/args_util.py 1 2 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/project/mylib/args_util.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import list_util as lu
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

## Solution

I settled for a Bash/Python polyglot solution. The Bash version of the program just calls `python3 -m mylib.args_util` then exits.

The Python version ignores the Bash code because it's contained in the docstring.

The Bash version ignores the Python code because it uses `exec` to stop parsing/running lines.

**`mylib/args_util.py:`**

```py
#!/bin/bash
# -*- Mode: python -*-
''''true
exec /usr/bin/env python3 -m mylib.args_util "$@"
'''

import sys
from . import list_util as lu

def parseargs(args):
    return sum(lu.to_int_list(args))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f'{parseargs(sys.argv[1:])=}')
```

### Output

```
$ ./main.py 1 2 3
mylib.args_util.parseargs(sys.argv[1:])=6

$ mylib/args_util.py 1 2 3
parseargs(sys.argv[1:])=6
```

### Explanation

- Line 1: `#!/bin/bash`; this is the "shebang" line; it tells the interactive shell how run this script.

  - Python: ignored (comment)
  - Bash: ignored (comment)
- Line 2: `# -*- Mode: python -*-` optional; this is called the "mode-line"; it tells Emacs to use Python syntax highlighting instead of guessing that the language is Bash when reading the file.

  - Python: ignored (comment)
  - Bash: ignored (comment)
- Line 3: `''''true`

  - Python: views this as an unassigned docstring starting with `'true\n`
  - Bash: views this as three strings (of which the first two are empty strings) that expand to `true` (i.e. `'' + '' + 'true' = 'true'`); it then runs `true` (which does nothing) and continues to the next line
- Line 4: `exec /usr/bin/env python3 -m mylib.args_util "$@"`

  - Python: still views this as part of the docstring from line 3.
  - Bash: runs `python3 -m mylib.args_util` then exits (it doesn't parse anything beyond this line)
- Line 5: `'''`

  - Python: views this as the end of the docstring from line 3.
  - Bash: doesn't parse this line

### Caveats

- This doesn't work on Windows:

  - *Workaround:* Use WSL or a Batch wrapper script to call `python -m mylib.args_util`.
- This only works if the current working directory is set to `/path/to/project/`.

  - *Workaround:* Set `PYTHONPATH` when calling `/usr/bin/env`

    ```
    #!/bin/bash
    # -*- Mode: python -*-
    ''''true
    exec /usr/bin/env python3 \
        PYTHONPATH="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")/.." ; pwd)" \
        -m mylib.args_util "$@"
    '''
    ```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: I needed a Linux service and cgi plugin which use common constants to cooperate. The 'natural' way to do this is to place them in the **init**.py of the package, but I cannot start the cgi plugin with the -m parameter.

My final solution was similar to Solution #2 above:

```
import sys
import pathlib as p
import importlib

pp = p.Path(sys.argv[0])
pack = pp.resolve().parent

pkg = importlib.import_module('__init__', package=str(pack))
```

The disadvantage is that you must prefix the constants (or common functions) with pkg:

```
print(pkg.Glob)
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving the file from which you are importing to an outside directory helps.
This is extra useful when your main file makes any other files in its own directory.
Ex:
Before:

```
Project  
|---dir1  
|-------main.py  
|-------module1.py
```

After:

```
Project  
|---module1.py  
|---dir1  
|-------main.py
```

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR; Append Script path to the System Path by adding following in the entry point of your python script**.

```
import os.path
import sys
PACKAGE_PARENT = '..'
SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.expanduser(__file__))))
sys.path.append(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR, PACKAGE_PARENT)))
```

Thats it now you can run your project in PyCharma as well as from Terminal!!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because of a misunderstanding in setup.py
You might not ever need this answer but while using setup.py to install my package from a folder I had this configuration:

```
packages=setuptools.find_packages(include=["package_folder.*"])
```

This is wrong as it was not supposed to have

```
.*
```

And should have been:

```
packages=setuptools.find_packages(include=["package_folder"])
```

It's just that the package was not installed properly, a deviation from relative imports.

Answer (score -1):

If the following import:

```
from . import something
```

doesn't work for you it is because this is [python-packaging](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html) import and will not work with your regular implementation, and here is an example to show how to use it:

Folder structure:

```
.
└── funniest
    ├── funniest
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── text.py
    ├── main.py
    └── setup.py
```

inside `__init__.py` add:

```
def available_module(): 
    return "hello world"
```

`text.py` add:

```
from . import available_module
```

inside `setup.py` add

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='funniest',
  version='0.1',
  description='The funniest joke in the world',
  url='http://github.com/storborg/funniest',
  author='Flying Circus',
  author_email='flyingcircus@example.com',
  license='MIT',
  packages=['funniest'],
  zip_safe=False)
```

**Now, this is the most important part** you need to install your package:

```
pip install .
```

Anywhere else in our system using the same Python, we can do this now:

```
>> import funnies.text as fun
>> fun.available_module()
```

This should output 'hello world'

you can test this in `main.py` (this will not require any installation of the Package)

Here is `main.py` as well

```
import funniest.text as fun 
print(fun.available_module())
```

Answer (score -1):

As this topic is still very unclear for most of us: aka 'how more complex scenario would work in-terms of relative imports in Python' (when your module **is not just one .py-script** in a folder, but N-classes grouped in more complex folder-hierarchy, like more complex modules often are.). Tbh, I think it does not, or at least everything related to that particular problem is so vaguely told, explained and documented online, that it is really difficult to understand how do it even nearly "right" or similar to for example C# namespaces.

So, as there are many good answers already to relative imports in more simple modules, I would like to give a shout on this to show a bullet-proof(ish) way & show the potential "blocker" to get your custom package with more complex modules to provide relative import internally (taken developing your own python program with >script-complexity), as there are some claims that Python3.3+ would handle these without `__init__()` files and so on. I found that claim partly false, as I tried all the given tricks (regarding use of relative, not absolute path)).

So, lets begin:

In order to enable relative references between package's N modules, **you do need at least one(1) `__init__.py` file that defines the visibility to your custom modules**.

Example:

in order to solve relative imports for good between N custom modules implemented to your custom package:

Logic that applies when wanting to enable relative imports such as defined above:

Taken the package and its modules are something like below:

```
`
<path to>/custom_package_folder
<path to>/custom_package_folder/my_module_a/my_custom_manager.py
<path to>/custom_package_folder/my_module_b/folder_x/subfolder_y/my_class_x.py
<path to>/custom_package_folder/my_module_n
`
```

At the /custom_package_folder:

Add:

```
`
__init__.py
`
```

And in `__init__.py` add:

```
`
from . import my_module_a
from . import my_module_b
from . import my_module_n
`
```

Now taken that the 'my_module_a/my_custom_manager.py':

```
`
class my_custom_manager():
    def my_func():
        print("message from module_a my_custom_manager class")
`
```

Now, you can access any custom module made visible for your package as demonstrated above, without need for absolute paths (or even `sys/os cwd` magic).

For example if we run: 'my_module_b/folder_x/subfolder/my_class_x.py':

```
`
# import any class from my_module_<N> via relative referencing made
# possible by offering visibility via your package's __init__.py
    
from my_module_a import my_custom_manager
    
mr_man = my_custom_manager() 
mr_man.my_func()
`
>>> 'message from module_a my_custom_manager class'
```

Why the above works is that visibility between our two own modules (a,b) has been granted via package's `__init__.py` configuration that allows the separate modules see each other.

If you're building any larger package/software in Python, there is no real reason to not manage properly these allowances/restrictions of the visibility properly anyway, as that is what they are (for designing / implementing higher level software architecture).

**Note 1:** I have found it really easy-when the program includes more modules, or modules include N classes, to build the software in a 'V'-flow, where objects in the same hierarchy-level of the program never access each other directly (i.e. code design patterns like 'module A <--> module B <--> module N <--> module A', will create huge mess when your program scales-up, so accessing in V shape i.e. through a separate manager module designed for managing such N modules. 'V'-shape **is good** any **other shape is not that good** (triangle, square or pentagon) in order to avoid weird unexpected "surprises" :)

**Note 2:** if you wish to control your program visibility in more granular detail & keep relative imports within your software,(at least in theory) you can abstract your program into layers with namespaces, in order to group your custom modules and manage their visibility in more exact manner:

1. Add namespace_folder(s) under your package root & divide your
   modules into the namespaces your want.
2. In package root's `__init__.py` import only the namespaces (in similar manner as above) that you wish to offer visibility here between each other.
3. Now in each namespace, add each namespace `__init__.py`, that list those modules you wish to allow visibility between and offer support for relative paths, while accessing each other.
4. So package provides/restricts visibility to N namespaces, namespaces provide/restrict visibility between & to their modules x,y,z with `__init__.py` files defined.

^^ Note, if you define on package level `__init__().py` so that your modules a,b,c can see each other (into global namespace) and then you have folder that groups modules d,e,f so that they form non-global namespace, lets say a_2.

Now if on this group parent folder you add `__init__().py` and include d,e,f modules to it in order to provide relative imports from these modules **to the global** namespace classes **and also to their shared non-global** namespace's module-n's children-classes (that are located in module's local hierarchy-tree in N-depth) --> Python actually does sh** on itself in errors with the latter one big time. It seemed to be that one cannot import from module n-1's child class module n's child class relatively to the namespace defined.

Might be that I am missing something, but Python seem to work on this particular use-case entirely differently than any OOP-languages I been using before (like C# for instance), which might connect to the fact Python has no real code encapsulation (private/public class/functional level etc...). Correct if I am wrong, I had no time to observe more deeper Python's interesting design philosophy.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem and solved it by creating a *symbolic link* to the package in the working directory:

`ln -s ../../../my_package my_package`

and then import it as usual:

`import my_package`

I know this is more like a "Linux" solution rather than a "Python" solution. but it's a valid approach nonetheless.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem and after struggling I've solved it by using the below code:

```
%run fileName.ipynb
```