# How to add a local library to a conda environment?

Tags: python, pip, conda, local, libraries

I have a project folder with a lot of different sub-folders in it. There are some functions I want to use in many different notebooks and scripts. For this reason, I decided to package them and install them in my environment so that I can reliably access them within the environment. The problem now is that it looks like the package is installed. However, I can't import it into scripts or notebooks.

This was my attempt to install the utils package in the enabled environment:

```bash
conda install conda-build -y
cd /home/path/to/project/tools/utils
conda develop .
pip install -e .
```

the commands `which pip`, `which python` and `which conda` lead to the path

```
/home/user/miniconda3/envs/env_name/bin/
```

the command `conda list | grep utils` will show:

```bash
utils                     1.0.0                     dev_0    <develop>
```

My `./tools/utils/setup.py` looks as follows:

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="utils",
    version="1.0.0",
    author="My Name",
    description="A collection of useful functions for the Project",
    install_requires=[
        "requests>=2.25.1",
        "numpy>=1.20.2",
        "pandas>=1.2.4",
        "matplotlib>=3.4.2",
        "opencv-python>=4.5.2.54",
        "tqdm>=4.60.0"
    ]
)
```

I thought there might be an error with the conda installation, so I moved the whole project to a Windows machine, set up the environment there as well, and installed the utils package. On both machines, when I run

```bash
python 
>>> import utils
```

in the environment, the response is:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

Since its the same on both my devices, I guess something must be wrong with my environment setup, or the installation process of the local editable library. For this reason, I did not bother to reinstall conda yet.

I'm hoping someone can give me some hints on how to solve this... Thank you in advance.

**Update**: I reinstalled miniconda on the Linux machine, renamed the package in the `setup.py` file to "myutils" and removed the requests dependency and made a wheel file with

```bash
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

so that i can use the packaged version, installing it using

```bash
pip install ./dist/myutils-1.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

I still have the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an problem with the project structure: after moving the source files to a new folder with the name of the project it works fine:

```
package_folder/
| myutils/
| | __init__.py
| | my_utility_a.py
| | my_utility_b.py
| setup.py
```

thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14421176/13507815) for the explanaition.